# What is the equation for the empty space created when centrifugally casting?

Tags: centrifugal-force

When metal is centrifugally cast, it is poured into a circular die which then spins, forcing the metal outwards to create a cylindrical part.

Im attempting to create a visualization of this phenomenon that correctly displays the effects that different parameters can have on the final result, projecting result in a 3d model.

The dimensions of the liquid’s container (radius and depth), the RPM, the type of alloy, and the approximate heat of the metal are all known. Also known is the inner radius of the final part.

What would be the equation, or series of equations, that could describe the shape of the empty space obtained from the metal spinning outwards? Is more information needed? Is it even realistically possible to model it with this simple of a generalization or are actual simulations needed?

Comment: If you don't get any answers, you might look into mirror making.  The Hubble Space Telescope mirror was made in the same way you describe.  And they are obviously quite interested in that precise shape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this](http://maecourses.ucsd.edu/%7Evlubarda/research/pdfpapers/Acta2013.pdf) research paper I was able to find the correct equation on page 17/18 for simulating with no surface tension.

Radius from the center of the container (r)
Angular velocity (ω)
Container radius (R)
Gravity (g)

h + (((R^2 * ω^2) / 4g) * (2 * ((r^2 / R^2) − 1)))